Help me understand jerk of a falling object hitting an "ideal foam"
I'm trying to calculate the theoretical minimum thickness of an "ideal foam" for a given jerk and acceleration limit.
Say we have a ball in free fall from $1.83 \,\text{m}$, reaching $6 \,\text{m}/\text{s}$. It then reaches an "ideal foam" for decelerating it. I'm trying to understand the connection between the thickness of the material and the connection to peak acceleration/peak jerk.
Basically: how thin a foam can theoretically be, while keeping acceleration/jerk under a given limit.
So, let's suppose our "ideal foam" is $5 \,\text{cm}$ thick.
If I'm correct, we can say that with constant acceleration, the lowest theoretical peak acceleration is:
$$a = \frac{v^2}{2s} = \frac{36}{0.1} \,\text{m}/\text{s}^2 = 360 \,\text{m}/\text{s}^2 \approx 36 g.$$
The time in this case is
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2s}{a}} = \sqrt{\frac{0.1}{360}} \,\text{s} \approx 0.016 \,\text{s}.$$
The problem with constant acceleration is that it means infinite jerk. How can I keep the same peak acceleration ($\approx 36g$) while limiting jerk? I guess I need to raise thickness, there is no way around it, right?
Also, I'm trying to understand, how does this problem look if the object is falling on a linear spring? How does a linear spring (as in Hooke's law) behave in terms of jerk and acceleration?

I mean let's say I can create any material I want. It can be a "magic" spring or a "magic" foam, or any layer of variable density foams. I'm interested in the theoretical limits on such a material. Basically I'm trying to calculate a lower boundary on an ideal material, from which real world materials would have to be thicker.
So I'm interested in the direction of:
to have max. $X$ peak acceleration and max. $Y$ peak jerk, I need at least $Z \,\text{cm}$ thickness. How can I calculate $Z$?

You can probably use the same analysis for an object facing air resistance except in this case the density is also a function of vertical distance traveled. Have you tried doing any of this yet?
